# Flutter routing with showDialog

Tags: flutter

I have been trying for a long time to get the user to press the button to be sent to another page of the application but I have not been able to solve it. Any suggestions for my problem?

I include my code.

```
showDialog<String>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
   AlertDialog(
    title: Row(
    children: const <Widget>[
     Icon(
     Icons.check,
     color: Color(0xff1E88E5),
    ),
    SizedBox(
     width: 6.0,
    ),
    Text('¡Correo enviado!')
   ],
  ),
  content: const Text(
  'Hemos enviado las intrucciones para recuperar la cuenta vinculada con el correo ingresado.'),
 actions: <Widget>[
  TextButton(
   onPressed: () {
    Navigator.pop(
     context, 'OK');
   },
   child: const Text(
   'Está bien',
   style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 18.0),
   ),
  ),
 ],
),
```

These were some of the codes used.

````
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()),
   ModalRoute.withName('/auth/login'));

Navigator.pushNamed(
  context, '/auth/pre-register');```
````

Comment: what code have you tried for pushing to new screen ?

Comment: Hi @WassefHassine.
I have already integrated it in the question, thanks.

Comment: First of all u just edited your code and added what i asked you, And what's the displayed error ? when you click on button to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

This code will reload your main screen

```
TextButton(
    onPressed: () {
         Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
              super.widget));
           },
       child: const Text('Reload Screen'),
    ),
```

If You would like to push to a new screen just change this code

```
 Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                  super.widget));
```

to

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
  );
```

Comment: Hi. Your solution was not for me, but thank you for your time.